# can GCC print out intermediate results?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, avr-gcc

Check the code below:

```
#include <avr/io.h>

const uint16_t baudrate = 9600;

void setupUART( void ) {
        uint16_t ubrr = ( ( F_CPU / ( 16 * (float) baudrate ) ) - 1 + .5 );
        UBRRH = ubrr >> 8;
        UBRRL = ubrr & 0xff;
}

int main( void ) {
        setupUART();
}
```

This is the command used to compile the code:

```
avr-gcc -g -DF_CPU=4000000       -Wall -Os -Werror -Wextra -mmcu=attiny2313 -Wa,-ahlmns=project.lst -c -o project.o project.cpp
```

`ubrr` is calculated by the compiler as 25, so far so good. However, to check what the compiler calculated, I have peek into the disassembly listing.

```
000000ae <setupUART()>:
  ae:   12 b8           out     UBRRH, r1       ; 0x02
  b0:   89 e1           ldi     r24, 0x19       ; 25
  b2:   89 b9           out     UBRRL, r24      ; 0x09
  b4:   08 95           ret
```

Is it possible to make `avr-gcc` print out the intermediate result **at compile time** (or pull the info from the .o file), so when I compile the code it prints a line like `(uint16_t) ubbr = 25` or similar? That way I can do a quick sanity check on the calculation and settings.

Comment: Have you tried the `-S` option?

Comment: @devnull Doesn't that exit the compiler? I want the compiler to finish the job, just print out an intermediate calculation it did.

Comment: If you just don't pass `-Os`, you'll probably get exactly what you want to see in the disassembly.  You probably don't want to ship that way, though. ;-)

Comment: @CarlNorum :o) Even with the -Oc flag I spot the useful information since you gave the hint, but I'd have to write an extra little script to extract the info and it probably easily breaks when I change the source code. Good hing though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC has command line options to request that it dump out its intermediate representation after any stage of compilation.  The "tree" dumps are in pseudo-C syntax and contain the information you want.  For what you're trying to do, the `-fdump-tree-original` and `-fdump-tree-optimized` dumps happen at useful points in the optimization pipeline.  I don't have an AVR compiler to hand, so I modified your test case to be self-contained and compilable with the compiler I do have:

```
typedef unsigned short uint16_t;
const int F_CPU = 4000000;
const uint16_t baudrate = 9600;
extern uint16_t UBRRH, UBRRL;

void 
setupUART(void)
{
    uint16_t ubrr = ((F_CPU / (16 * (float) baudrate)) - 1 + .5);
    UBRRH = ubrr >> 8;
    UBRRL = ubrr & 0xff;
}
```

and then

```
$ gcc -O2 -S -fdump-tree-original -fdump-tree-optimized test.c
$ cat test.c.003t.original
;; Function setupUART (null)
;; enabled by -tree-original


{
  uint16_t ubrr = 25;

    uint16_t ubrr = 25;
  UBRRH = (uint16_t) ((short unsigned int) ubrr >> 8);
  UBRRL = ubrr & 255;
}

$ cat test.c.149t.optimized
;; Function setupUART (setupUART, funcdef_no=0, decl_uid=1728, cgraph_uid=0)

setupUART ()
{
<bb 2>:
  UBRRH = 0;
  UBRRL = 25;
  return;
}
```

You can see that constant-expression folding is done so early that it's already happened in the "original" dump (which is the earliest comprehensible dump you can have), and that optimization has further folded the shift and mask operations into the statements writing to UBRRH and UBRRL.

The numbers in the filenames (003t and 149t) will probably be different for you.  If you want to see *all* the "tree" dumps, use `-fdump-tree-all`.  There are also "RTL" dumps, which don't look anything like C and are probably not useful to you.  If you're curious, though, `-fdump-rtl-all` will turn 'em on.  In total there are about 100 tree and 60 RTL dumps, so it's a good idea to do this in a scratch directory.

(Psssst: Every time you put spaces on the inside of your parentheses, God kills a kitten.)

Comment: Nice one! I can do a `grep -E '^[ \t]*uint16_t ubrr' project.cpp.003t.original` which looks like apretty robust workaround to me

Answer (score 2):

There might be a solution for printing intermediate results, but it will take you some time to be implemented. So it is worthwhile only for a quite large source code base.

You could customize your GCC compiler; either thru a plugin (painfully coded in C or C++) or thru a [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension. MELT is a high-level, Lisp-like, domain specific language to extend GCC. (It is implemented as a [meta-]plugin for GCC and is translated to C++ code suitable for GCC).

However such an approach requires you to understand GCC internals, then to add your own "optimization" pass to do the [aspect oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) (e.g. using MELT) to print the *relevant* intermediate results.

You could also look not only the generated assembly (and use `-fverbose-asm -S` as options to GCC) but also perhaps in the generated Gimple representations (perhaps with `-fdump-tree-gimple`). For some interactive tool, consider the graphical [MELT probe](http://gcc-melt.org/#probe_id).

Perhaps adding your own builtin (with a MELT extension) like `__builtin_display_compile_time_constant` might be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is an easy way to determine what the compiler does. There may be some tools in gcc specifically to dump the intermediate form of the language, but it will definitely not be easy to read, and unless you REALLY suspect that the compiler is doing something wrong (and have a VERY small example to show it), it's unlikely you can use it for anything meaningful - simply because it is too much work to follow what is going on.

A better approach is to add temporary variables (and perhaps prints) to your code, if you worry about it being correct:

```
    uint16_t ubrr = ( ( F_CPU / ( 16 * (float) baudrate ) ) - 1 + .5 );
    uint8_t ubrr_high = ubrr >> 8
    uint8_t ubrr_low = ubrr & 0xff;
    UBRRH = ubrr_high;
    UBRRL = ubrr_low;
```

Now, if you have a non-optimized build and step through it in GDB, you should be able to see what it does. Otherwise, adding printouts of some sort to the code to show what the values are...

If you can't print it on the target system because you are in the process of setting up the uart that you will be using to print with, then replicate the code on your local host system and debug it there. Unless the compiler is very buggy, you should get the same values from the same compilation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hack: simply automate what you are doing by hand now.

- In your makefile, ensure that avr-gcc produces a disassembly (`-ahlms=`*output.lst*). Alternatively, use your own dissassembly method as a post-compile step in your makefile.
- As a post-compilation step, process your listing file using your favorite scripting language to look for `out UBRRH` and  `out UBRRL` lines.  These are going to be loaded from registers, so your script can pull out the immediately preceeding assignments to registers that will be loaded into `UBRRH` and `UBRRL`. The script can then reassemble the `UBRR` value from the value loaded into the general-purpose registers which whhich are used to set  `UBRRH` and `UBRRL`.

This sounds to be easier than [Basile Starynkevich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/841108/basile-starynkevitch)'s very useful suggestion of [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension.  Now, granted that this solution *seems* fragile, at first blush, so let's consider this issue:

- We *know* that (at least on your processor) the lines `out UBRR_, r__` will appear in the disassembly listing: there is simply no other way to set the registers/write data to port.  One thing that might change is the spacing in/around these lines but this can be easily handled by your script
- We also know that `out` instructions can only take place from general-purpose registers, so we know there will be a general-purpose register as the second argument to the `out` instruction line, so that should not be a problem.
- Finally, we also know that this register will be set prior to `out` instruction. Here we must allow for some variability: instead of `LDI` (load immediate), avr-gcc might produce some other set of instructions to set the register value. I think as a first pass the script should be able to parse immediate loading, and otherwise dump whatever last instruction it finds involving the register that will be written to `UBRR_` ports.

The script may have to change if you change platforms (some processors have `UBRRH1`/`2` registers instea of `UBRRH`, however in that case you baud code will have to change. If the script complains that it can't parse the disassembly then you'll at least know that your check has not been performed.

Comment: UBRRH will show r1 which is usually set to 0 on startup (using an `eor r1,r1`, but it is really difficult to be sure about that.

Comment: Well, at worst your script could print the `eor r1,r1` using the "print the last thing involving the register that is used to set the port" heuristic. Or you could write a mini AVR simulator in your script, teaching it that XOR-ing a value with itself means "set it to zero" :)